# How to get the result from a query function reside in another file? (Javascript, phoneGap and Sqlite)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I wanted to separate my main.js file from my sqlite function file. How can I get the result of the query to the main.js (fr anotherFile.js).

```
//In main.js
function getResult() {
    queryDB(); //how to get d result from queryDB() ?
}
```

```
// In anotherFile.js:
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess(tx, results) {
    for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) { 
        //what to put here, Array?
    }
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//anotherFile.js:

function queryDB(tx, callbackMethod) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], callbackMethod, onError);
}
```

---

```
//main.js

function sendQuery() {
    queryDB(tx, queryResult);
}

function queryResult(tx, results) {
    for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) { 

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i found out that i can just cut n paste any function into another file. It will works just fine.